# Make a while loop with counter

Tags: r, loops, while-loop

I am trying to calculate the number of agents that a call center should have but the results hardly change each other.

This number of agents is calculated in the ***resource*** function, which will return a column with the results. The number of agents will increase until the desired service level is reached (***gos_target***). So, if **gos<gostarget**, the number of agents will be increased by 1 and a new value of *gos* will have to be computed. In order to calculate the new value of *gos* *service_level*, I need to calculate the function *erlang_c*.

We call the *resource* function as follows: resource(rate = i, duration= 103, target= 20, gos_target=85/100, interval = 3600); where all data except ***rate*** is fixed. *Rate* is the number of calls received, that is, in my data I have a column where in each row there is a number of calls received depending on the time, day... and what is intended is that the function go row per row obtaining the number of agents according to the number of calls.

For example, if the third row has a value of = 200. It means that 200 calls were received in that hour, therefore, with that number the *intensity* = 10 will be calculated, then the *erlang_c* = 0.6821, service_level = 0.390 and finally *resource* = 14 = number of agents.
**The expected results must be similar to these but with notable variations depending on the number of calls.** The higher the number of calls, the lower the service_level.

**The problem is that when compiling I get values that are very similar to each other**, which doesn't make sense. It should not be the same if you receive 7 calls an hour as if you receive 50.

**Here is the data:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mEUW3rI659_FlkqFuzXY9xzDrDxNIm2q/view?usp=sharing

Here is the code:

```
ds <- dataset

library(dplyr)

intensity <- function(rate, duration, interval) {
   return (rate / interval) * duration
}

erlang_c <- function(agents, rate, duration, interval) {
   int <- intensity(rate, duration, interval)
   erlang_b_inv <- 1
   for (i in 1: agents) {
     erlang_b_inv <- 1 + erlang_b_inv * i / int
   }
   erlang_b <- 1 / erlang_b_inv
   return (agents * erlang_b / (agents - int * (1 - erlang_b)))
}

service_level <- function(agents, rate, duration, target, interval) {
   pw <- erlang_c(agents, rate, duration, interval)
   int <- intensity(rate, duration, interval)
   #a <- (pw * exp(-(agents - int)))
   #b <- (target / duration)
   to <- exp(-(agents-int)*(target/duration))
   return (1 - (pw*(a)))
}

resource <- function(rate, duration, target, gos_target, interval) {
   inten <- intensity(rate, duration, interval)
   agents <- ceiling(inten + 1)
   gos <- service_level(agents, rate, duration, target, interval)

   while (gos < gos_target) {
     agents <- agents + 1
     gos <- service_level(agents, rate, duration, target, interval)
   }
   return(c(agents,gos))
}


vec_agents <- c()
gos_vec <- c()

for (i in ds$calls) {
   #print(i)
   res <-resource(rate = i, duration= 103, target= 20, gos_target=85/100, interval = 3600)
   vec_agents <- c(vec_agents, res[1])
   gos_vec <- c(gos_vec, res[2])
}


ds$agents <- vec_agents
ds$gos <- gos_vec
```

I can't see what might be going on. Help me please!!
Greetings.

[image]

Comment: You have a lot going on there that can be modified.  But first off, your `gos` object appears to be a scalar, yet you index it in your `while` loop as if it's a vector.  If `gos` is a scalar, then `gos[1]` will return `gos` but every other `gos[i]` will return `NA`.  You should also use explicit `return` in all your functions for validation.  There is more you can do to clean up what you got.

Comment: Hi Steve! Thank you so much for your answer. I have fully edited the code. It compiles fine but it gives me an invalid result. I get all the values very similar to each other and I don't know why. I have edited the post with the new code and more detailed information in case you could help me.

Comment: As Steve said, you have a lot going on here and you are not providing data, thus making your code not reproducible. It's not obvious what is wrong in your code unless we can test it.  As a general advice, I would break the problem up into pieces. Go through each of your custom functions and test them to make sure they behave as intended.

Comment: If you can find where the error is occurring, I would encourage you to provide some test data as you would prior to using the problematic part of your code, and indicate what output you would expect to get out of it. In order to get help, you need to provide a *minimally reproducible* example.

Comment: You're right Phil! I have uploaded the data now. I don't know how to upload the file otherwise. I hope it's accessible. In the maintime, I'm dividing it into smaller pieces. Thank you for your answer!